# Can I define in any way color of array's element?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to make 2D map but I have problem with setting a color for  all elements which value is 'a' 
is it possible in any way??
^^^

```
if(map[a][b]=='a')
set color ..... ;  

void map_create(int lenght, int wide,char map[][100])
{

    for(int i=0; i<lenght; i++)
    {
        for(int i2=0; i2<wide-1; i2++)
        {
            if(i2==0)
            {
                map[i][i2]='x';
                continue;
            }
            if(i2%2!=0)
            {
                map[i][i2]=' ';
                continue;
            }
            if((i==0 || i==lenght-1) || (i2==0 || i2==wide-2))
               map[i][i2]='x';
            else
                map[i][i2]=' ';


        }


    }
    map[2][2]='o';
    if(tab[i][i2]=='o')
    {
        int problem_is_here;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give a lot more explanation about what you're trying to do, what you've done, and what isn't working? As it stands, this question doesn't make much sense. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips

Comment: Did this not work `if(map[a][b]=='a') set color`? Did it give an error message?

Comment: Are you trying to draw the map to the terminal using colored characters?

Comment: One issue is that color is not part of standard C++.  We'll need more context about what you are trying to accomplish.  Please edit your post with actual code.

Comment: Your edit did not really help. Again `color` has no meaning in standard `c++`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's function to create the map, and I have no idea how can I set color of elements :/ Then I want to print it by simple function

 void rendering(int lenght, int wide, char map[][100])
{
   for(int i=0,i2=0;i<lenght;i++,i2++)
    {
        cout.write(map[i],wide-1);
        cout<<'\n';
    }
}
For example I want to have my all 'o' elements to be printed in blue colour

Comment: Are you trying to print to the console using different colors with cout statements?

Comment: Yes but I want to console knows about colour of every element, is it possible??

Comment: Is this on linux?

Comment: Nope windows here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053837/colorizing-text-in-the-console-with-c

Comment: ^^ Yes but i print all the line of chars so all line will be for exmple green :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the 2D map (e.g. to terminal), this may be a duplicate. Reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal) for more information.