# How make qDebug to write method and class name?

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

I want to make the `qDebug` or `qWarning` method to write the class and method name that calling them.Now I writing like below but It is hard work for all class and method in my application.Does Any one know How can I do this?

```
void File::downloadingFinishd()
{
    qWarning()<<"File::downloadingFinishd()";//How write this ?without manually doing this?
    qDebug()<<"Download was succceed";
}
```

I want something Like android because I see in output that it writing method and class name with diffrent color Just with calling `qDebug()`

Comment: I still use these: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q_FUNC_INFO` is the Qt version of std pretty function.

From [Qt Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_FUNC_INFO):

> const char*  Q_FUNC_INFO
>
> Expands to a string that describe the function the macro resides in.
>   How this string looks more specifically is compiler dependent. With
>   GNU GCC it is typically the function signature, while with other
>   compilers it might be the line and column number.

If you want to avoid verbosity in client code, you can define your own macro with a `Q_FUNC_INFO`, for instance:

```
#define qPrettyDebug() qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
#define qPrettyWarning() qWarning() << Q_FUNC_INFO

void File::downloadingFinishd()
{
    qPrettyWarning()<< "Download was succceed";
    qDebug() << "here I don't want to print again the function context";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make use of Q_FUNC_INFO macro.

```
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "debug stmt";         ==> Qt way
qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "debug stmt"; ==> c++ way
```

To color use this thread [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54062826/5903276)

Answer (score 2):

take a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qSetMessagePattern

So you can use for example in your main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qSetMessagePattern("%{function} %{message}");
    ...
}
```

Comment: qSetMessagePattern is nice, but prevent you to choose when doing a pretty printing and when not.