# How to color output in C for cross-platform app

Tags: c, windows, gcc, g++, clang

I am new and I know how to color output only in Unix/Linux systems:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("\033[1;31mRed Message\033[0m.");
}
```

But this is not works in Windows cmd.exe, only in Unix terminal.

I am writing cross-platform app and want to know how can I do this in Windows cmd.exe too.

This also does not works:

**1.**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%c[1;31mRed Message%c[0m", 27, 27);
}
```

**2.**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("[1;31m Red Message [0m");
}
```

**This works, but I think this is just a bug:**

If I type `system("");` before `printf` then it works.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    system("");
    printf("\033[1;31m Red Message \033[0m");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This used to work in windows if the cmd.exe window supported ansi escape sequences.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Comment: More related info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line

Comment: This all not worked in cmd.exe, I saw this URLs already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your library crossplatform, I would use the following approach:
Have a library, with the same functions, let's say:
`void printInRed(const char* string)`. (In a headerfile)
After that you write two or more implementations.
One for windows:

```
//TODO: Errorchecking
void printInRed(const char* string){
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    //TODO: Extract magic number
    //See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053879/13912132
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);
    puts(string);
}
```

And another one for unix-like OS:

```
//TODO: Errorchecking
void printInRed(const char* string){
    printf("\033[1;31m%s\033[0m.", string);
}
```

Then you can check at compile time, which version to compile.
The first approach is to use `#ifdef`s, but this will make the code a bit messy.

Another approach would be to use a build-system like `CMake` to select at build time, which one to build. A buildsystem requires a bit of learning, but will help you to make maintaining a crossplatform library simpler.

Comment: I found very strange way, if I type `system("")` before `printf`, then colors works: