# How to implement command line coloration?

Tags: c, bash, unix, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [color text in terminal aplications in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585846/color-text-in-terminal-aplications-in-unix)

I am working on a small Unix shell (written completely in C), and am wondering how to copy `bash`'s prompt coloring technique. Are there libraries to do that? Has anyone ever tried them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple shell escape commands like `\033[31mRed\033[0m` or use the `ncurses` library.

Googling `ncurses` will give you all you need to get started.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do colorization in the unix shell is to use a library like curses / ncurses.  It provides a portable way to implement items like corolization in the unix shell.

Here's a link to a nice tutorial on it

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/color.html