# How to print italic text in f-strings in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, printing, jupyter-notebook, f-string, italic

I am trying to use `f-strings` to print some parts of text in italic format.

Browsing the web for `"python"+"print"+"italic"+"f-strings"`, I found these ANSI codes should do the work : `'\x1B[3m'` and `'\x1B[0m'` ; although they don't :

```
print(f'\x1B[3m italic \x1B[0m' + f'not italic')
```

gives no italic output :

```
italic not italic
```

Am I missing some update?
My python version is 3.9.7 and I'm using `Jupyter Notebook`.

Comment: ANSI escape codes only work on the command line (in a terminal). They don't work in graphical applications.

Comment: But I used `print(f'\033[1m CITY \033[0m')` and it works and gives me **CITY**

Answer (score 1):

In Jupyter Notebooks, you can use

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
display(Markdown("normal *italic* normal"))
```

See
[printing bold, colored, etc., text in ipython qtconsole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271575/printing-bold-colored-etc-text-in-ipython-qtconsole), https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934204/747202

Answer (score 0):

ANSI escape work with `python` or `ipython`, but only in the terminal.

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: Well, so I don't understand why it works in my Jupyter Notebook if I ask for `bold` text but not if I ask for `italic` text...? Very strange.

Comment: They might have implemented a subset of all ANSI sequences.