# How can I make text bold in Python?

Tags: python, text, input, format

I want to be able to change the text to bold in Python. Is there a way to do that?

I have been able to change colors with termcolor but nothing so far with bold text. Has anyone tried doing it before?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to try ANSI escape sequences **if** your platform allows it.

Crossposting from related - and possible duplicate - SO questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/python-print-bold-text) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

Before you proceed, please read the warnings in the above links to make sure your operating system and Python version will allow you to properly render this.

You can define a class containing all of the ANSI escape sequences you need.

```
class style:
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   END = '\033[0m'
```

Then `print` them via concatenated class calls:

```
print style.BOLD + 'This is my text string.' + style.END
```

If you don't want to go through the hassle of creating an entire class just to get bold text, you can obviously concatenate them directly instead. However, if your code is open-source and not for personal use, make sure you tell other potential readers what this does!

```
print '\033[1m' + 'This is my text string.' + '\033[0m'
```

Does this answer your question?

Edit: JYelton beat me to it. I'm such a slow typer...