# How to print bold text in python with ```format```?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm aware of the [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834876/how-can-i-make-text-bold-in-python) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python) when using string concatenator `+`. However I couldn't find how to do it with the **new printing style** (more details [here](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align)), e.g. `print '{:10s}'.format(str)`.

Comment: @khelwood it is not.

Comment: When you tried to use the solutions given in those other questions (via `.format` if that's what you want), what code did you try, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: But i see it as different question, here the question very specific and wants to know how to make text bold in DOCUMENT string i.e """ document text """  or  ''' document text '''


The given url points to a question to make the text bold in console which is using print!!! is it not!??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same ANSI escape sequences work just fine.

```
print('\033[1m{:10s}\033[0m'.format('foo'))
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would made the answer great!!

Comment: Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code