# How would I print this underlined and center

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I make the following display center and underlined in the shell (if I can)

```
print ("Award show",datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))
```

Comment: Idk if you can underline ik you can add spaces to the front to make it centered

Comment: When you start asking questions like this, you'll probably want to look at a tool like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) (or one of it's many simpler counterparts). An answer for which is probably out of scope here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print something underlined in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401019/how-do-i-print-something-underlined-in-python)

Comment: Can your shell print underlined text? Can you determine its width in characters?

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to add this code

```
print  '  ' +   '\033[4m' + 'Text here' +  '\033[0m'
```

first part is to add spaces,

second part is making it underline,

3rd part is text 4th part is end of the whole thing

Then to center just add spaces to the first