# Is it possible to underline/bold text in a Windows 10 Notification (python win10toast module)?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

I am developing a program that generates a notification upon completion. It is clickable and I would like to exaggerate this by underlining or bolding "Click here" in the notification. Is this possible? If it's not a feature in win10toast, is there another module I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```py
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

def return_with_underline(x):
    lst1 = []
    for letter in x:
        if letter != ' ':
            lst1.append(letter)
            lst1.append('\u0332')
        else:
            lst1.append(letter)
    return '{:s}'.format(''.join(lst1))

toaster = ToastNotifier()

toaster.show_toast(return_with_underline('Click Here!'), "Hi", icon_path=None, duration=5)
```

This is not perfect (does not work with spaces), but you can use other Unicode characters too, instead of `\u03232`

Got this from here (they are talking about plain strings but it works here too):

[Python: String formatter to get underlined headline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55065640/python-string-formatter-to-get-underlined-headline)

Comment: would you mind marking my answer as the correct one by click the check mark? Thanks!!