# python underline "\u0332" not working in Kali Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I'm trying to underline my text in python using `Unicode "\u0332"`**
*I'm using Kali Linux and I'm running this code in `Kali terminal` to run this Code.*
**Here is my Python Code.**

```
# This will print Unicode Character ('combining low line' U+0332) as underlines 

#sentence = s
s = "$Hello I want to underline my text$"

if (s[0]=="$" and s[len(s)-1]=="$"):
    s = s[1:]#removes first $
    s = s[:-1]# removes last char $
    s = "\u0332".join(s)
print(s)
```

**Output I want**

```
 H̲e̲l̲l̲o̲ ̲I̲ ̲w̲a̲n̲t̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲ ̲m̲y̲ ̲t̲e̲x̲t
```

**Output I'm getting**

```
Hello I want to underline my text
```

Comment: Not all terminals and fonts support all Unicode features.

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: You could try using ANSI Escape sequences - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55065815/5320906