# Seemingly perfect code written on TextWrangler gives SyntaxError when run on Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, textwrangler

This is my code:

```
def trip(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_cost(ride):
    if ride == "London":
        return 220
    elif ride == "Rome":
        return 200
    elif ride == "Glascow":
        return 185

def car_rental(days):
    cost = 20 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost = cost - 25
    if days >= 3:
        cost = cost - 10
    return cost

def tripcost(ride, days, spending_pounds):
    trip(days) + plane_cost(ride) + car_rental(days) + spending_pounds

print tripcost("London", 5, 500)
```

Was wondering why the word `tripcost` (marked in bold) was shown to be a syntax error when I loaded it in idlE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print bold text in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python)

Comment: I bet TextWrangler is Python 2 and your IDE is connected to an installation of Python 3. Is that the case? Try changing that last line to `print(tripcost("London", 5, 500))`.

Comment: @JRazor - I think OP just has asterisks to point out the line with the error. Nothing else in the question makes any indication of wanting bold text.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the **full text** of the syntax error.

Comment: Unless an IDE does something extra, which IDLE does not, SyntaxErrors come from the python x.y parser/compiler.  Similarly, the editor used is irrelevant, unless it changes what you type, which IDLE also does not.  If the report is accurate, this must be a 2 versus 3 syntax change issue.

Comment: Side note: Your `tripcost` function is missing a `return` statement.

Comment: The problem is that in Python 3, `print` is a function, not a statement.  Just as `str 4` is invalid syntax, so is `print tripcost(...)`.  You need to add the parentheses.  In this case, it isn't necessary to change anything for Python 2, but usually if you want to maintain backwards-compatability, you should put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add at the beginning of the script `from __future__ import print_function` and change `print tripcost("London", 5, 500)` on `print(tripcost("London", 5, 500))`