# Changing text font and colour

Tags: python

Whether it's a module or something I can define in my code, is there a way to change the output text like making it *italic* or **BOLD**? Also, are colours a thing?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17303428/2999446

Comment: thank you! @LukeK, i did look but didnt find anything like this.

Comment: @LukeK it doesnt have italics :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print bold text in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python)

Comment: Do you mean the appearance of text in your system's shell/console? Or in a text file that you generate with Python? Or something else?

Comment: Code for italics is \x1B[3m. Add something like ITALIC = "\x1B[3m" to the class they have there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the question @LukeK posted, you can use [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code?wprov=sfla1) anywhere in your strings:

```
print("Roses are \033[31mred\033[0m") # Will make red... red
```

You can combine them in that way (I hope it's clear enough):

```
BOLD_AND_RED = "\033[1;31m"
```

On the other hand, you can find modules that allow simpler (or nicer) ways of doing it, but I prefer writing code with minimal dependencies, so I usually put some global variables and I later concatenate them with my strings:

```
RED    = "\033[31m"
BOLD   = "\033[1m"
ITALIC = "\033[3m"
RESET  = "\033[0m"

print(BOLD + RED + "ERROR: " + RESET + ITALIC + "blah blah...")
```

Last note! This escape sequences only work in terminals, and I don't think they work in Windows cmd.