# Printing elements of a list in bold

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, text

I have a list of names like

```
names = ['a b c', 'd e f', ...]
```

and I need to print these names in a plot using bold for some of them. So I'm using for example

```
for k in range(len(names)):
    if k in [0,2]:
       plt.text(x,y, '$\\bf{' + names[k] + '}$')
    else:
       plt.text(x,y, names[k])
```

but in this way names in bold are printed like `abc` instead of `a b c`. Of course `'$\\bf{names[k]}$'` just prints **`names[k]`**. What is the correct way of doing this?

I have also tried the answers here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python) without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mathtext` has the unfortunate side-effect of stripping spaces. You need to escape the spaces (with `\`) to make it work.

However, if you don't specifically need to use mathtext, I would suggest you use [the `fontdict=` option to `Text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html?highlight=text#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) to change the weight to bold.

Here is how I would do it:

```
names = ['a b c', 'd e f', 'g h i']
bold = [True, False, True]
xys = [(-3,-1),(0,0),(2,1)]
for n,doBold,xy in zip(names,bold,xys):
    t = ax.text(*xy, n, fontdict={'fontweight': 'bold' if doBold else 'normal'})
```

[image]