# How to make specific part of email body bold in python?

Tags: python, email

I am using smtp, mac, python 2.7.

Tried this: [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python)

```
text = "This is the text"
bold_text = "This is the \033[1m text \033[0m"
print(bold_text)
```

result:

> This is the \033[1m text \033[0m

Comment: Read other answers in that link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python)