# How to make input text bold in console?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to make the text that the user types in the console bold

```
input("Input your name: ")
```

If I type "John", I want it to show up as bold as I'm typing it, something like this

> Input your name: **John**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python does this work?

Comment: @yosukesabai It only works when you print things using print(), I want it to show up as bold right away when you type it in the console. Also I've already seen that, didn't help but thanks though

Comment: Are you in linux? stty may be able to change your output to bold

Comment: I'm on windows. Also again, I'm not really looking for a way to print text in bold. I'm looking for a way to make the input text bold. But thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called **ANSI escape sequence**. Basically you output some special bytes to control how the terminal text looks. Try this:

```
x = input('Name: \u001b[1m')  # anything from here on will be BOLD

print('\u001b[0m', end='')  # anything from here on will be normal
print('Your input is:', x)
```

`\u001b[1m` tells the terminal to switch to bold text. `\u001b[0m` tells it to reset.

[This page](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html) gives a good introduction to ANSI escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you! I knew about ansi escape sequences but I didn't know you can use them this way

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with **colorama**:

```
from colorama import init,Style,Fore,Back
import os

os.system('cls')

def inputer(prompt) :
    init()
    print(Style.NORMAL+prompt + Style.BRIGHT+'',end="")
    x = input()
    return x

## -------------------------

inputer("Input your name: ")
```

and the output will be as follows:

> Input your name: **John**

ref. : https://youtu.be/wYPh61tROiY