# Print bold keywords in a text

Tags: python

keyword_list = ['cat', 'dog']

string = 'I have a dog and a cat'

Say I have defined keyword_list and string, how can i print the string with keywords bold:

'I have a **dog** and a **cat**'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python for more information

Comment: use `print('\033[1m' + 'Hello')`

Answer (score 0):

Use replace to add **bold** to the front of the target text and then end the escape with the end chars on the other side of each target text:

```py
BOLD = '\033[1m'
END = '\033[0m'

keyword_list = ['cat', 'dog']

string = 'I have a dog and a cat'

for i in keyword_list:
   string = string.replace(i, BOLD + i + END)

print(string)
```

More info [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)