# Write bold text to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i just want to write a string to a text file with part of this one in **bold**.

Is there any way to do it?

An example of what i am asking for:

> **2021/02/19**: this is an example

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924173/how-do-i-print-bold-text-in-python/8930747) answer your question?

Comment: No you cannot. `txt` means a plain text file. Plain means without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any type of markdown in a `.txt` file, using python or not.
You might want to check other files extensions such as `.md` files.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = 'teste.rtf'
out_file = open(test,'w')
out_file.write("""{\\rtf1
This is \\b Bold  \\b0\line\
}""")
out_file.close()
```

Comment: This is not a `txt` file, so this isn't an answer. Please add explanation.

Comment: This depends if you are using linux / unix:
you can customize the output command

Comment: run ```print '\033[1m' + 'Hello'```
and run back if write ```print '\033[0m'```