# How to make a text bold using python

Tags: python, string, bold, colorama

I need to make a string to bold. I have used:

```
from colorama import init,Fore, Back, Style
```

y='Hello world'

I want to pass the bolded 'y' to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to look into https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich :)

```py
from rich import print

print("Hello, [bold magenta]World[/bold magenta]!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to do that generally. However, using [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303428/16384299), you can probably establish your own Bold class best suited to your needs.

```py
import colorama

colorama.init()  # catch the format on windows to print correctly


class Format:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'


class Bold(str):

    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t

    def asHTML(self):
        """Returns the text formated for HTML usaage"""
        return f"<b>{self.t}</b>"

    def asMD(self):
        """Returns the text formated for additions to markdown files, like for example a README.md"""
        return "**" + self.t + "**"

    def __str__(self):
        return Format.BOLD + self.t + Format.END


y = 'Hello world'
y = Bold(y)
print(y)
print(y.lower())  # not actually in bold ! 
# Do not forget to overwrite any function like this to 'reboldify' the text
```

which for me prints :

**Hello world**

hello world