# How to print text with specific format to a printer in Python?

Tags: python, text, printing

I am printing a text string to a printer like so:

```py
import os

string_value = 'Hello, World!'

printer = os.popen('lpr -P Canon_iP110_series', 'w')
printer.write(string_value)
printer.close()
```

This works perfectly, printing the text to the printer in what I assume is the default font/color (black).

I want to change some features of the text, though. For example, I want to bold the word 'Hello', perhaps, or print 'World' in green maybe.

I have found several answers having to do with "printing" text, but they're giving escape codes relating to the terminal/console output - not to a printer. Eg, [How can I print bold text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8924173/1107226)

These escape codes do work when I print the string to the console. Eg,

```py
bold_on = '\033[1m'
bold_off = '\033[0m'

string_value = '{0}Hello{1}, World!'.format(bold_on, bold_off)

print(string_value)
```

does output:

> **Hello**, World!

to the console. However, it does not bold the 'Hello' text on the printer.

How can I bold text at least, and possibly change other font attributes, when printing text to a printer in Python?

(Python 3.9+)

Comment: It depends on what the driver for that printer is doing with your string. It's likely treating it as (or wrapping it in) a program for whatever language your printer interprets (likely [PCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language)). One option (the only option?) would be to generate the PCL yourself and print it with `lpr -o raw -P Canon_iP110_series`.

Comment: If you know more about the driver being used, it might be able to handle a format that's easier to generate, like RTF, PS, PDF, etc.

Comment: Ah, so Python has no `AttributedString` class or similar module like Java or Swift, then, @chepner? I couldn't find one in searching, anyway.

Comment: No. Even if it did, it would only be usable in your Python code, not by the printer driver used by `lpr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chepner commented, it seems Python is pretty basic when it comes to printing text to a printer. What I ended up doing instead is using [FPDF v1.7.2](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf/) to place the text in a PDF file. Sending the file to the printer, then, outputs the text with the attributes I defined.

The `FPDF`-related functions in my example should work the same on all platforms.
The printer-related functions in this example should work on macOS and Linux. Windows would require different methods for printing.

```py
import os  # for printing to printer
from fpdf import FPDF  # for pdf creation

# set up pdf basics:
pdf = FPDF('P', 'pt', 'Letter')  # P(ortrait), points size ref, Letter-size paper
pdf.add_page()  # add a blank page to start
pdf.set_font('helvetica', size=12)  # optional here, but useful if most text is plain

hello_string = 'Hello'
world_string = ', World!'

# set font to B(old) *and* I(talic)
pdf.set_font('helvetica', size=12, style='BI')

# write string into PDF page, stopping at end of string; line height = 6 pts
pdf.write(h=6, txt=hello_string)

# change back to regular font
pdf.set_font('helvetica', size=12)

# write rest of string into PDF
pdf.write(h=6, txt=world_string)


# output the created page(s) as a PDF file
pdf_filename = 'hello_world.pdf'
pdf.output(pdf_filename)


# finally, print the PDF file to the printer
printer_name = 'Canon_iP110_series'
printer_string = 'lpr -P {0} {1}'.format(printer_name, pdf_filename)
os.system(printer_string)
```

Notes:

- I had to play with line heights to resolve some overlapping
- Some FPDF functions allow for `\n` line breaks in the string, while others don't. `write` does allow for line breaks and will stop wherever the string stops. The next `write` function begins where the last one stopped.
- FPDF also has functions to set text color - among some other interesting features
- [FPDF documentation](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf) has moved around. I found a number of examples with a search. As of 17 March 2023, I was able to access [Reingart's FPDF tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/master/docs/Tutorial.md), which gives some great examples
- To locate the desired printer name, use `lpstat` (note the `-d` is optional; when the `-d` is used, `lpstat` also displays which printer is set as default):

  `lpstat -p [-d]`