# How to read byte object from text file without double backslash?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a byte object from a text file, but whenever I read from the text file I get double backslashes in the bytes object and I cannot find out how to revert them to single backslashes. The file is opened as `open(file, 'rb')`. I've tried using encode and decode and I've also tried using `eval(str(my_string).replace('\\\\','\\'))` as detailed in other answers, but all have returned the error: `SyntaxError: (value error) invalid \x escape at position 372`. The string I am trying to read is: `\xde\xcct\x18\xe5*\x91\xcc\xf1\xb4\xe9\xc2\x97BhR\x87\xd6x\xd8\x83\x8b\xc2\x08`

Edit:

The answers detailed in [Reading utf-8 escape sequences from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933784/reading-utf-8-escape-sequences-from-a-file) and other questions haven't helped, since I still get a unicode escape error when trying the methods.

Comment: The file is in bytes or is it the escaped string? Have you tried printing it?

Comment: The file just contains the escaped string: `\xde\xcct\x18\xe5*\x91\xcc\xf1\xb4\xe9\xc2\x97BhR\x87\xd6x\xd8\x83\x8b\xc2\x08`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I .decode('string-escape') in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820429/how-do-i-decodestring-escape-in-python3#14820462), then

Answer (score 1):

If your string coming from file with characters escaped by backslashes, the backslashes are correctly backlashed themselves and then you can see the single backslash as double backslashes. What you certainly want is getting the escaped characters translated. You can use codecs module with unicode_escape for this:

```
with codecs.open("<yourfile>", 'r', encoding="unicode_escape") as fr:
    print(fr.read())
```

If you are encountering errors, you have a flag to decide what will happen by opening the file with "unicode_escape" encoding parameter.

```
with codecs.open("<yourfile>", 'r', encoding="unicode_escape", errors="ignore") as fr:
    print(fr.read())
```

You can see a full list of error handlers here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers

Comment: Just tried that, got error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 372-374: truncated \xXX escape` (The actual string is massive so I only showed the first part)

Comment: It seems that you have a problematic file with incorrect escaped sequences in it. The easiest solution would be to handle the errors, I will update my answer.