# How to write execute c program code with colour format?

Tags: c, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

Files should get white font,directory should be in blue font and executable file should be in green font.

Comment: possible duplicate of [color text in terminal aplications in unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585846/color-text-in-terminal-aplications-in-unix)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANSI sequences which are supported by most consoles.

`printf("\x1b[34m" "Blue text");`

`printf("\x1b[32m" "Green text");`

and use `"\x1b[0m"` to set it back to the default colour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN  "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN  "\x1B[36m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"


int main(void){
    printf(KRED "This is KRED\n"RESET);
    printf(KGRN "This is KGRN\n"RESET);
    printf(KYEL "This is KYEL\n"RESET);
    printf(KMAG "This is KMAG\n"RESET);
    printf(KCYN "This is KCYN\n"RESET);

    return 0;
}
```

After you setup your favorite color do not forget to allways set it back to its default one.