# ANSI escape codes not displaying correctly

Tags: c, ansi-colors

I have the following defines:

```
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\e[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\e[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\e[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\e[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\e[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\e[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\e[0m"
```

I then use these like so:

```
char *getStatusColour(eTaskState state) {
    switch (state) {
        case eRunning:
            return ANSI_COLOR_GREEN;
            break;
        case eReady:
            return ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW;
            break;
        case eBlocked:
            return ANSI_COLOR_RED;
            break;
        case eSuspended:
            return ANSI_COLOR_BLUE;
            break;
        case eDeleted:
            return ANSI_COLOR_RESET;
            break;
    }

    return ANSI_COLOR_RESET;
}

printf("%s TEST %s\n", getStatusColour(eRunning), ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
```

The terminal output, however, does not work (IE: No colours and where the colour "should" be, is an unknown character (IE: Something not displayable).

Any ideas why this would not be working?

**EDIT**

It should be noted I get some colours printing when I change to:

```
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN \e[32m\\]
```

But the text is truncated, and I'm not sure what the `\\]` does.

Comment: Not every output device supports ANSI escapes. Which one are you using?

Comment: @RossRidge I'm using a terminal on UNIX with 256 colour support.

Comment: @Ruud, no luck, that just prints `\e[32m` at the start of each line and `\e[0m` at the end.

Comment: Have you tryed [this format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3586005/4944425)?

Comment: @Bob__ same issue that I had originally sadly.

Comment: The color goes IN the format string not as part of a format specifier. e.g. `printf ("ANSI_COLOR_RED %s\n", somestring);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how do you mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin would that not simply act the same as I have currently?

Comment: Can you confirm with this minimal code: `printf("%s TEST %s\n", "\e[31m", "\e[0m");`; if this works the problem is in code that is not present in the question; if it does not work, then your terminal does not work.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That works (Prints TEST in red)

Comment: @JosephGarrone what about [this](https://ideone.com/L5Z9NE) slightly less minimal example?

Comment: then the problem is in the code that is not present in your question. Perhaps `eRunning` is uninitialized.

Comment: eRunning is an enum. I'll investigate more tomorrow. Thanks all for suggestions. Worst case I can just move the print into the switch and duplicate code.

Comment: note that you do not have a `default` case, so if the value is invalid, then color reset escape is returned. Perhaps you'd want to print an error in the `default`.

Comment: Also you do not need `break` after `return` I guess, unless this is some funny arduino C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that `\e` is not a standard escape code and may thus fail **(behaviour is undefined!)**:

```
% gcc ansi.c -pedantic
ansi.c: In function ‘main’:
ansi.c:4:12: warning: non-ISO-standard escape sequence, '\e'
     printf("\e[1;32mfoobar");
```

Use `\033` or `\x1B` instead.

Comment: I've tried with both `\033` and `\x1B` to no avail. But point noted, I won't use `\e` (I'm used to it from shell)

Comment: However, I tried your code and, well, **it works for me**.

Comment: Looks like it might be somewhere else in the pipeline then. I'm interfacing from an Arduino to `kermusb` on a UNIX terminal.