# Colored text in console

Tags: c, colors

I would like to make colored text in console for each char (text). I tried to use
`system("COLOR <COLOR_CODE>");`
but it takes effect for all text. Can I color only some text?

Thank you very much for help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color text in terminal applications in UNIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585846/color-text-in-terminal-applications-in-unix)

Answer (score 1):

In the Window console, to color text you need to call [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047(VS.85).aspx).
For example,

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
```

Make sure to include `<windows.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote a cool header a while back:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
enum colors {
    black = 0,
    electric = 1,
    leaf = 2,
    lightblue = 3,
    red = 4,
    darkpurple = 5,
    gold = 6,
    lightgrey = 7,
    grey = 8,
    blue = 9,
    green = 10,
    aqua = 11,
    lightred = 12,
    purple = 13,
    yellow = 14,
    white = 15,
};
namespace color {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    void print(std::string text, const int font = colors::lightgrey, const int background = colors::black) {
        bool inv = false;
        if (text[text.length() - 1] == '\n') {
            text.pop_back();
            inv = true;
        }
        int color;
        color = background * 16 + font;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, color);
        printf(text.c_str());
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7);
        if (inv)
            printf("\n");
    }

    void printM(std::string text, const int color) {
        bool inv = false;
        if (text[text.length() - 1] == '\n') {
            text.pop_back();
            inv = true;
        }
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, color);
        printf(text.c_str());
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7);
        if (inv)
            printf("\n");
    }

    void map(const char* e = NULL)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            printM(std::to_string(i), i);
            printf(e);
        }
    }
};
```

The only downside is that if you're doing multithreading some stuff will get colored with other.

Answer (score -1):

Put 
`#define color(param) printf("\033[%sm", param)
  #define green "32"
  #define white "0"`

at the beginning of your file.

Then, use `color(green)` before your printf.
32 is for green, feel free to try other numbers to find what you like.

Comment: Those are ANSI color codes, and they haven't worked in Windows since about Windows XP.