# C function to print color text with formatting

Tags: c, printf, ansi-escape

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585846/color-text-in-terminal-applications-in-unix) helped me to print in different collors.

Iam trying to create a function which always prints the given `char*`in blue. I got so far:

```
#define KBLU  "\x1B[34m"
#define KWHT  "\x1B[37m"

void infoPrint(char* msg, ...)
{
    printf("%s", KBLU);
    printf(msg);
    printf("%s", KWHT);
}
```

When i call the function:

```
int value = 42;
infoPrint("Show value: %d.\n", value);
```

Iam getting the following output **in the color blue**:

```
Show value: 0.
```

For any reason the value `42` is not passed correctly.

If i change the function `void infoPrint(char* msg, ...)`to:

```
void infoPrint(char* msg, ...)
{
    printf(msg);
}
```

Iam getting the output (obviously in standard terminal color):

```
Show value: 42.
```

What happens to the value 42? Why is it 0 if I try to print in blue before printing the actual message?

Thank you

Comment: You need to use `vprintf`; if you use `printf` without giving proper arguments, the behaviour is *undefined*, and unfortunately it might even look as if it *works*, as in your 2nd case.

Comment: @Antii Haapala Thank you this really is a duplicate. Didnt know what to google exactly. Should i delete this one?

Comment: No, on the contrary, you've got upvotes here too, let it be open if someone else is wondering about the same thing.